# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MutableCoercionConfig;"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss7.x

```
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MutableCoercionConfig;
[cvgDeployer]     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; 
  nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MutableCoercionConfig;
[cvgDeployer]     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; 
  nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MutableCoercionConfig;
[cvgDeployer]     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MutableCoercionConfig;"}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

I am using JBoss 7.3.3 GA and spring boot 2.5.5

I want to develop rest API using spring boot and JBoss 7.3.3 GA

can anyone will help to resolve this issue ? this is something related to Jackson dependencies

Comment: That is very likely because of dependency version incompatible.
Check if running SpringbootTest work(to see problem is related to jboss or not).
And also include your pom/gradle dependency here

Comment: JBoss EAP already ships with Jackson. Make sure you're not including Jackson in your deployment.